# Make changes in 2 database objects, but only in accordance with one another

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-design, mongoose

I have 2 mongoose database objects `user` and `game` like:

```
 User = {
    game : game.Id
    // each user has a game attachetd to it
 }
 Game = {
    users : [user.Id, user.Id, ...]
    // game has a list of users who have it attached to them
 }
```

I want to perform a 'removeGame' operation on both these objects.

Remove the game from a user, and remove the corrosponding user from the game's array.

But I want it to be in accordance with each other. I.e. I shouldn't end up with a user with game attached to it who's array doesn't have that user, or a game's array with a user who doesn't have the game attached to it.

I can't figure out the logic to do this.

```
UserSchema.methods.removeGame = function(gameId) {
    //remove 
    this.game = null;
    //save
    this.save(function(err, user){
        if(!err) {
            // then remove the user from game
            // something with #1 below
            // call 
            game.removeUser(this.id);
            // but #2
        }
        else {
            // don't remove the user from game
            // also see #3
        }
    });
}

GameSchema.methods.removeUser = function(userId) {
    //remove
    this.users[userId]= null;
    //save
    this.save(function(err, game){
        if(!err) {
            // then remove the game from user
            // something with #1 above
        }
        else {
            // don't remove the game from user
            // #2 
            // if this happens, undo removing the game from the user above
            // same for above #3
        }
    });
}
```

Any advice how should I do this?

Could promises be helpful in my case?

Should I be putting this kind of logic in the database object itself in the first place?

Should I redesign my database?

Comment: Is there a special reason to have redundant data? I would remove the game field from the user altogether, and get the users games via `db.game.find({"users":user.id})` on a multi key index created with `db.game.ensureIndex({"users":1})`. This way you don't have redundant data any more, and a player unsubscribing from a game is as easy as `db.game.update({"users":user.id},{$pull:{"users":user.id}})`. No fuzz, no problems, no code to maintain, fast.